# Haskell function that returns a sorted list of points depending on how close they are to a certain point

Tags: haskell

I have the following three functions. The function "distance" calculates the distance between two points. The function "calculatesDistances" takes a point (x1, y1) and a list of points [(x2, y2)] and uses the "distance" function to calculate the distance between (x1, y1) and every (x2, y2) in the list [(x2, y2)]. It returns a sorted list of points depending on their distance to (x1, y1). The function "closestDistances" returns the n closest points to (x1, y1) and it uses the sorted list from the function "calculatesDistances".

I think my algorithm is correct but as you can see my code for "calculatesDistances" is missing because I have no idea how to write this in Haskell. I am a beginner and I'm really struggling with Haskell syntax. Any help will be appreciated.

```
distance :: (Floating a, Ord a) => (a,a) -> (a,a)-> a
    distance (x1 , y1) (x2 , y2) = sqrt (x'*x' + y'*y')
        where
          x' = x1 - x2
          y' = y1 - y2

    Example outputs:
    *Main> distance (0,0) (1,0)
    1.0
    *Main> distance (0,0) (2,0)
    2.0
    *Main> distance (0,0) (3,0)
    3.0


    calculatesDistances :: (Floating a, Ord a) => (a,a) -> [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
    Psesudocode:
    Apply function distance to (x1 , y1) and every (x2 , y2) in [(x2 , y2)] and get a distance for every input
    Return the list [(x2 , y2)] but sorted in ascending order depending on the distance

    Expected output:
    *Main> calculatesDistances (0,0) [(3,0), (2,0),(-3,0), (1,0)]
     [(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(-3,0)]


    closestDistances :: (Floating a, Ord a) => Int -> (a,a) -> [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
    closestDistances n (x1, y1) [(x2, y2)] = take n (calculatesDistances (x1, y1) [(x2, y2)])

    Expected output:

    *Main> closestDistances 3 (0,0) [(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(-3,0)]
     [(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)]

    *Main> closestDistances 2 (0,0) [(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(-3,0)]
     [(1,0),(2,0)]
```

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=sort

Comment: I know about this function but the sorting of the list depends on the outputs of the function "distance" for every two points. So how can I use it in this case?

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=sortBy

Comment: `sortBy (comparing distance) list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sortOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn), which has type

```
sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
```

and which sorts the `a`s by comparing the output of the `a -> b` function. For example,

```
Data.List> sortOn (distance (0,0)) [(3,0), (1,1), (0,1)]
[(0.0,1.0),(1.0,1.0),(3.0,0.0)]
```

You might also consider writing a `squaredDistance` function which omits the `sqrt` for efficiency, since `sqrt` is monotonic and hence does not affect sort order.

Comment: I got this error:
<interactive>:92:1: error:
    Variable not in scope:
      sortOn :: ((Double, Double) -> Double) -> [(Integer, Integer)] -> t

Comment: @user408340 Did you import `Data.List`? What version of `base` do you have (you can ask with `ghc-pkg list base`)?

Comment: No, I forgot to import it. Thank you very much!